# Tensorflow - how do I calculate the loss weighting for multiclass classification problems and apply it to the loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an unbalanced dataset that I use to train my Neural Network. The number of labels in the dataset corresponding to the classes I've counted is below:

`training_data_classnums = [1480, 1104, 1261, 942, 2612, 1109, 355, 355]`

I use Softmax to calculate the probabilities of each class in the loss function:

```
training_data_classnums = [1480, 1104, 1261, 942, 2612, 1109, 355, 355]
class_sum = sum(training_data_classnums)
training_data_weights = [x / class_sum for x in training_data_classnums]
print("class_weights {}".format(training_data_weights))
...
onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=8)
class_weight = tf.constant(training_data_weights)
weighted_logits = tf.multiply(logits, class_weight)
tf.logging.info("logits_weighted {} {}".format(weighted_logits.get_shape(), logits.get_shape()))
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=weighted_logits)
```

Is this the correct way to calculate the weights for each class, and is this the right way to apply it into the loss calculation? (I use the `tf.Estimator`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loss function for class imbalanced binary classifier in Tensor flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155655/loss-function-for-class-imbalanced-binary-classifier-in-tensor-flow)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement a weighted cross entropy loss in tensorflow using sparse\_softmax\_cross\_entropy\_with\_logits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198364/how-can-i-implement-a-weighted-cross-entropy-loss-in-tensorflow-using-sparse-sof)