# how to scale and renormalize the output with tensorflow softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits for class imbalance

Tags: tensorflow, softmax, cross-entropy

I want to scale the model output and renormalize it to deal with the class imbalance issue. For example, if I have 10-labels outputs `y_logits` and their softmax `y_pred` and prior `p`, the new output should be:

```
y_pred /= prior
y_pred /= sum(y_pred)
```

The problem is that `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` function in tensorflow takes the logits `y_logits` and I need to do this scaling on `y_pred` instead. Any idea how to do that without implementing the cross-entropy loss myself?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198364/how-can-i-implement-a-weighted-cross-entropy-loss-in-tensorflow-using-sparse-sof ?

Comment: I see that there is someone suggested to do it with `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy`, is there a way to do a similar thing with `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` instead?

Comment: The same trick works for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are faceing the same problem, I've found a good solution for it by reimplementing the CE in a numerically stable way. If you want to know why you shouldn't implement CE directly as its equation says `-∑ p_i log(q_i)` check out this [tutorial](http://python.usyiyi.cn/documents/effective-tf/12.html).

The implementation I used to apply the priors works as follows:

```
def modified_CE(logits=None, labels=None, priors=None):
    # subtracting the maximum value to prevent inf results
    # you should change the shape of your logits based on your data
    scaled_logits = logits - tf.reshape(tf.reduce_max(logits,1),shape=(7500,1))
    # renormalize your logits as a finale step for the log softmax function
    normalized_logits = scaled_logits - tf.reshape(tf.reduce_logsumexp(scaled_logits,1),shape=(7500,1))

    # apply the priors
    normalized_logits -= tf.log(np.array(priors,dtype=np.float32))
    # renormalize 
    normalized_logits -= tf.reshape(tf.reduce_logsumexp(normalized_logits,1),shape=(7500,1))

    return tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(labels[0,:,:]*normalized_logits,1))
```