# How correctly calculate tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits pos_weight variable

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, convolution

I am using convolution neural network.

My data is quite imbalanced, I have two classes.

My first class contains: 551,462 image files

My second class contains: 52,377 image files

I want to use `weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits`, but I'm not sure I'm calculating `pos_weight` variable correctly.

Right now I'm using

```
classes_weights = tf.constant([0.0949784, 1.0])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, targets=y_, pos_weight=classes_weights))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE, epsilon=1e-03).minimize(
      cross_entropy
    , global_step=global_step
    )
```

Or should I use

`classes_weights = 10.5287`

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation:

> pos_weight: A coefficient to use on the positive examples.

and

> The argument pos_weight is used as a multiplier for the positive targets:

So if your first class is positive, then `pos_weights = 52,377 / 551,462`, otherwise `551,462 / 52,377`

Comment: I was thinking this way, but I saw couple examples where people has used array of class coefficients as an input [source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42163122/1574139). Also running the code with `pos_weights = 10.5287` keeps loss at very high numbers. Even after 60600 iterations * 50 of mini batch has reached mean loss at some point over 1.0 which doesn't seem right. And it seems class 1 has way better accuracy already and class 2 is not improving that well.

Comment: @DariusŠilkaitis this is what documentation says, and I have more trust in it then in one lonely answer on SO. You tried with my approach and are not satisfied with the results, but have you tried another approach `tf.constant([0.0949784, 1.0])`?

Comment: training is quite slow on such big data. So I haven't tried both solutions deeply yet. With `tf.constant([0.0949784, 1.0])` loss seemed way too low for my eye, but I was getting better accuracy. It will take me couple days to try both configurations for at least 20 epochs each one. I'll update results here. Thanks for help.

Comment: @SalvadorDali trying this approach with a scalar value for pos_weight classifies all the majority class (0's) as the minortiy class (1's), substantially increasing False Positives. Any clue on why that may be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As @Salvador Dali said, the best source is the source code
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5b10b3474bea72e29875264bb34be476e187039c/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L183

We have

```
log_weight = 1 + (pos_weight - 1) * targets
```

so it only applies if `targets==1`.

If `targets==0` then `log_weight = 1`

If `targets==1` then `log_weight = pos_weight`

So if we have ratio of positives to negatives x/y we need pos_weight  to be y/x so both categories will contribute equally in total

Please note that each scalar in targets tensor corresponds to each category so each member of pos_weight corresponds to each category as well (not positive or negative probability  for one category) .