# How to implemet weighted loss for imbalanced data for multi-label classification in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

I have an imbalanced dataset,and my task is **multi-label classification**

this is my code for minimizing loss:

```
logits = inference(input)
xent = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        logits=logits, labels=labels, name='xent')
loss = tf.reduce_mean(xent, name='loss_op')
```

now.I want to use `weighted-loss` for my classification,exactly how can I do it? 
Can I use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155655/loss-function-for-class-imbalanced-binary-classifier-in-tensor-flow),and replace `softmax` with `sigmoid` ?

**Point**

I have read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43564490/how-correctly-calculate-tf-nn-weighted-cross-entropy-with-logits-pos-weight-vari),but my case is not binary classification
and in [tensorflow_org](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits) I think it is for binary classification too.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`tf.losses.compute_weighted_loss`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/compute_weighted_loss).  I suggest reading [the code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/losses_impl.py#L157-L214) to see exactly how this function works, but you should be able to do, roughly:

```
logits = inference(input)
xent = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    logits=logits, labels=labels, name='xent')
weighted_loss = tf.losses.compute_weighted_loss(xent, YOUR_WEIGHTS, name='weighted_loss_op')
```