# Unbalanced Binary Classification in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification

I am trying to perform a binary classification using tensorflow (V.1.1.0) with a single neuron at the output layer. The snippet below corresponds to the loss function and optimizer I am currently using (inspired from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38912982/7550636)).

```
ratio=.034 #minority/population ratio
learning_rate=0.001
class_weight=tf.constant([[ratio,1.0-ratio]],name='unbalanced_ratio') #weight vector, (lab_feed is one_hot labels)
weight_per_label=tf.transpose(tf.matmul(lab_feed,tf.transpose(class_weight)),name='weights_per_label')
xent=tf.multiply(weight_per_label,tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=lab_feed,logits=output),name='loss')
loss=tf.reduce_mean(xent)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate,name='GradientDescent').minimize(loss)
```

**My issue is however that for some reason all instances are classified as the same class after progression of epochs. Do I have to stop training in the middle or is there something wrong with the loss function?**

[image]

Comment: Do I understand your Training confusion Matrix correctly that there are 1800 training samples belonging to class 0 and only 130 belonging to class 1?

Comment: @B1T0 yes thats correct.

Comment: That is a problem. You will have to balance your dataset. There is lots of info on the internet about that topic. [This](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/) is a good intro imo.

Comment: @Flomp, Although I agree with you,In the code, there is a penalty in misclassifying the minority class. This approach is also known as weighed cross entropy and is a valid approach by itself.

Comment: As far as I understand your loss function should totally work as it is. If you are not under time pressure you could try to use TensorBoard to get information about the variables during training. I used it several times and sometimes I saw that they do not change during training. Then I restarted the training process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing sigmoid cross-entropy as if it were softmax cross-entropy.

Sigmoid cross-entropy is adapted to binary classification — your problem is binary classification, so that's fine. But then, the output of your net should have only one channel per binary classification task — in your case, you have a single binary classification task, so your net should have one output channel only.

To balance a sigmoid cross-entropy you need to balance each individual part of the cross-entropy, i.e. the part coming from the positive and the part coming from the negative. This cannot be done on the output, as you are doing, because the output is already a sum of the positive and negative parts.

Hopefully there is a function in tensorflow to do just that, [`tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits). Its use is similar to `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy` with an additional parameter corresponding to the weight of the positive class.

What you are currently doing, is having two binary classifiers on two different channels, and sending only the negative samples to the first and the positives samples to the second. This cannot produce something useful.