# Classification: What happens if one class has 4 times as much data as the other class?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to debug an issue with my classifier. The issue is that it always predicts the same class for a given input despite having close to an 80% accuracy.

I trained my CNN to detect the difference between 2 classes. class A has 2575 jpegs and class B has 665 jpegs.

Could this have caused my issue with my CNN always predicting the same class? Is this too much of an imbalance between the # of items in each class? In general, will my performance improve if I make the size of both classes the same(at 665 jpegs?)?

Comment: I think it is better to ask in [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem seems to be a case of class imbalance and there are different ways to handle it:

1. ***Weighted loss:***
      You can penalise the reward for the majority loss function by computing a [weighted cross entropy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155655/loss-function-for-class-imbalanced-binary-classifier-in-tensor-flow).
2. ***Resampling the data:*** As you mentioned you can also downsample the majority class, to balance the classes. You can also upsample the minority class to make it even.
3. ***Generate augmented data:*** Since you are handling images, you can upsample the minority class and then use `data augmentation` on those images, this solves the class imbalance as well as tackles overfitting and improves generalisation.
4. and Combination of all the above.

Comment: I like your answer @vijay. I wonder if (3.) can be harmful when data augmentation is only applied to underrepresented classes. Does the distortion in distribution pose a risk to the classifiers performance?

Comment: @Gegenwind what i meant is upsample under-represented classes and then apply data augmentation for all class.