# How to obtain weights map in multi class image classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-3.7, loss-function

I am doing a multiclass image segmentation using keras and TensorFlow. My trained network is giving me good predictions but fails to separate the touching objects, that's why I want to use `softmax_cross_entropy` loss function which has a `"weights"` parameter.

How can I calculate those weights knowing that my `y_true` shape is `(batch-size,128,128,3)`?

```
tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(y_true,y_pred,weights=my_weights)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy`, you can use that parameter to weight the samples from each batch differently and it should be a tensor of the shape `batch_size`.

> `weights` acts as a coefficient for the loss. If a scalar is provided,
>   then the loss is simply scaled by the given value. If `weights` is a
>   tensor of shape `[batch_size]`, then the loss weights apply to each
>   corresponding sample.

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35168022/9144990) shows how to assign different weights for each class (maybe you have an imbalanced dataset?). I guess this is more what you might want to achieve.

Comment: the distribution of classes in my labels are not the same so i assume my dataset is imbalanced. based on the answer in the link you posted they use `ratio` to calculate the `class_weight`, how can i find this ration when i have 800 training image labels ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sklearn to compute the [class weight](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html) for imbalanced dataset. And use those calculated parameters to assign `weights` in `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy`. This will help to tackle your issue.