# Implement custom loss function in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function, tensorflow2.0

I'm building a model for Time series classification. The data is very unbalanced so I've decided to use a weighted cross entropy function as my loss.

Tensorflow provides [tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits) but I'm not sure how to use it in TF 2.0. Because my model is build using tf.keras API I was thinking about creating my custom loss function like this:

```
pos_weight=10
def weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_true,y_pred):
  return tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_true,y_pred,pos_weight)

# .....
model.compile(loss=weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits,optimizer="adam",metrics=["acc"])
```

My question is: is there a way to use tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits with tf.keras API directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the class weights directly to the `model.fit` function.

> `class_weight:` Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to
>   a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during
>   training only). This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more
>   attention" to samples from an under-represented class.

Such as:

```
{
    0: 0.31, 
    1: 0.33, 
    2: 0.36, 
    3: 0.42, 
    4: 0.48
}
```

[Source](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

---

**Edit:**
[JL Meunier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155655/loss-function-for-class-imbalanced-binary-classifier-in-tensor-flow) explains well how to multiply the logits with class weights.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But could I get the same result by using my custom function instead of passing the weights to the `model.fit` function?