# Tensorflow 2.0 Custom loss function with multiple inputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to optimize a model with the following two loss functions

```
def loss_1(pred, weights, logits):
    weighted_sparse_ce = kls.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    policy_loss = weighted_sparse_ce(pred, logits, sample_weight=advantages)
```

and

```
def loss_2(y_pred, y):
    return kls.mean_squared_error(y_pred, y)
```

however, because TensorFlow 2 expects loss function to be of the form

```
def fn(y_pred, y_true):
    ...
```

I am using a work-around for `loss_1` where I pack `pred` and `weights` into a single tensor before passing to `loss_1` in the call to [`model.fit`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) and then unpack them in `loss_1`. This is inelegant and nasty because `pred` and `weights` are of different data types and so this requires an additional cast, pack, un-pack and un-cast each time I call [`model.fit`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit).

Furthermore, I am aware of the `sample_weight` argument to `fit`, which is kind of like the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414114/implement-custom-loss-function-in-tensorflow-2-0). This might be a workable solution were it not for the fact that I am using two loss functions and I only want the `sample_weight` applied to one of them. Also, even if this were a solution, would it not be generalizable to other types of custom loss functions.

---

All that being said, my question, said concisely, is:

What is the best way to create a loss function with an arbitrary number of
arguments in TensorFlow 2?

Another thing I have tried is passing a [`tf.tuple`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/tuple) but that also seems to violate TensorFlow's desires for a loss function input.

Comment: How about using closure? Basically, you can define a standard loss function, we named `inside_loss`, that only takes (`y_true`, and `y_pred`) inside your `loss_1`. You can pass weights or logits, any arguments to `loss_1`. Finally, your `loss_1` will return `inside_loss` this function. It pretty like how we customize keras loss function. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2121

Comment: @zihaozhihao Thats an interesting solution but it wouldn't work when using eager tensors or  NumPy arrays as inputs though.

Comment: Umm, do you mean the arguments of `loss_1`? If so, I'm sure that works.

Comment: Yes for `loss_1` and no it wouldn't work because the data captured by the closure is not available at the time of the creation of the closure.

Comment: TF 2.0 expects loss function to be of the form `def fn(y_true, y_pred)`, that is, y_true is the first argument.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem can be easily solved using [custom training](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough) in TF2. You need only compute your two-component loss function within a `GradientTape` context and then call an optimizer with the produced gradients. For example, you could create a function `custom_loss` which computes both losses given the arguments to each:

```
def custom_loss(model, loss1_args, loss2_args):
  # model: tf.model.Keras
  # loss1_args: arguments to loss_1, as tuple.
  # loss2_args: arguments to loss_2, as tuple.
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    l1_value = loss_1(*loss1_args)
    l2_value = loss_2(*loss2_args)
    loss_value = [l1_value, l2_value]
  return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)

# In training loop:
loss_values, grads = custom_loss(model, loss1_args, loss2_args)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```

In this way, each loss function can take an arbitrary number of eager tensors, regardless of whether they are inputs or outputs to the model. The sets of arguments to each loss function need not be disjoint as shown in this example.

Answer (score 7):

To expand on Jon's answer. In case you want to still have the benefits of a Keras Model you can expand the model class and write your own custom train_step:

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import data_adapter

# custom loss function that takes two outputs of the model
# as input parameters which would otherwise not be possible
def custom_loss(gt, x, y):
    return tf.reduce_mean(x) + tf.reduce_mean(y)

class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def compile(self, optimizer, my_loss):
        super().compile(optimizer)
        self.my_loss = my_loss

    def train_step(self, data):
        data = data_adapter.expand_1d(data)
        input_data, gt, sample_weight = data_adapter.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(data)

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(input_data, training=True)
            loss_value = self.my_loss(gt, y_pred[0], y_pred[1])

        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, self.trainable_variables)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_variables))

        return {"loss_value": loss_value}

...

model = CustomModel(inputs=input_tensor0, outputs=[x, y])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), my_loss=custom_loss)
```

Comment: I just tried your code... but do get the error "ValueError: The model cannot be compiled because it has no loss to optimize."
Working with Keras 2.3.0 and tensorflow 2.2.0

Comment: That usually means that you are either passing no loss function or a loss function without any gradients that can be used for optimization. E.g. if your loss function would just return a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

In tf 1.x we have `tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits` function which allows us trade off recall and precision by adding extra positive weights for each class. In multi-label classification, it should be a (N,) tensor or numpy array. However, in tf 2.0, I haven't found similar loss functions yet, so I wrote my own loss function with extra arguments `pos_w_arr`.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.backend import epsilon

def pos_w_loss(pos_w_arr):
    """
    Define positive weighted loss function
    """
    def fn(y_true, y_pred):
        _epsilon = tf.convert_to_tensor(epsilon(), dtype=y_pred.dtype.base_dtype)
        _y_pred = tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, _epsilon, 1. - _epsilon)
        cost = tf.multiply(tf.multiply(y_true, tf.math.log(
            _y_pred)), pos_w_arr)+tf.multiply((1-y_true), tf.math.log(1-_y_pred))
        return -tf.reduce_mean(cost)
    return fn
```

Not sure what do you mean it wouldn't work when using eager tensors or numpy array as inputs though. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This would work in TF 1.x where `pos_w_arr` is not an eager tensor. In TF 2 `pos_w_arr` is not available at the time of creation of the closure so `pos_w_arr` would have to be a constant. I am interested in the case where `pos_w_arr` varies across batches.

Comment: If possible, you can set `pos_w_arr` as `tf.keras.Input`.

Comment: Basically, when you fit your model, `x=[x_data,pos_w]`, `x_data` and `pos_w` are both `Input`.

Comment: In my case `pos_w_arr` needs to be an *output* of the model. Would `tf.keras.Input` be the right thing then?