# when to use tf.GradientTape during writing a custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am doing some reading on custom loss functions in `tensorflow` and was going through the example provided in the tutorials page (see the link below).

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough

Here is a simple loss provided in the link.

```
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

def loss(model, x, y, training):
  y_ = model(x, training=training)
  return loss_object(y_true=y, y_pred=y_)
```

Following this example, the author mentions that `Use the tf.GradientTape context to calculate the gradients used to optimize your model`.

My question is why one would need to use `tf.GradientTape`? Doesn't `tensorflow` actually computes the gradients when using any optimizer such as `Adam`?

In fact, I also looked at a previous question posted here.

[How to write a custom loss function in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875944/how-to-write-a-custom-loss-function-in-tensorflow)

You can see that none of the answers uses `tf.GradientTape`. I am sharing one of the answers posted, which makes lots of sense to me.

```
def focal_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  pt_1 = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true, 1), y_pred, tf.ones_like(y_pred))
  pt_0 = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true, 0), y_pred, tf.zeros_like(y_pred))
  custom_loss=kb.square((pt_1-pt_0)/10)
  return custom_loss    

model.compile(loss=focal_loss,
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

On the contrary, in another similar question, all the answers use `tf.GradientTape`.

[Tensorflow 2.0 Custom loss function with multiple inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022713/tensorflow-2-0-custom-loss-function-with-multiple-inputs)

At the moment, I am quite a bit confused. Could someone explain what's the use of `tf.GradientTape` and when should I consider using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how you are training your model. If you are using `model.fit` to train your model then you do not have to explicitly use `tf.GradientTape`, but it is still being used under the hood! If you define a custom training loop like the one in the walkthrough you referenced, you will have to use `tf.GradientTape`, which

> enables you to retrieve the gradients of the trainable weights of the layer with respect to a loss value. [Source](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch?hl=en)

Now regarding your question: The calculated gradients are formally partial derivatives or the measure of change, and your model's optimizer adjusts the individual weights of your model based on these gradients.